# $\left[\log ({x^2+y^2}) + \left(\frac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)\right]dx$ + $\left(\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)dy$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, logarithms, partial-derivative

Question: $\left[\log ({x^2+y^2}) + \left(\frac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)\right]dx$ + $\left(\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)dy$

So I found $\left(\frac{\delta(m)}{\delta(y)}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{\delta(n)}{\delta(x)}\right)$, where m = $[log ({x^2+y^2}) + \left(\frac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)]$ and n = $\left(\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)$, and I got $\left(\frac{2y^3-2x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{2y^3-2x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)}\right)$ respectively, i.e $\left(\frac{\delta(m)}{\delta(y)}\right)$ = $\left(\frac{\delta(n)}{\delta(x)}\right)$, which means this is an exact differential equation. Now I have to find $\int(m)dx$ considering y terms as constants and $\int$(terms of n not containing x)dy = c. I am unable to proceed from here on. Any help will be appreciated. Please and thank you.

Comment: I am afraid there is no question in the body of the text. Could you please specify what is the problem?

Comment: That isn't a question. Did you forget an $=0$ or something similar?

Comment: Please use \partial wherever you have \delta, no parentheses needed. It seems your denominators need a square, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to find $u(x,y)$ such that
$$
du = \left[\log ({x^2+y^2}) + \left(\frac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)\right]dx
+\left(\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)dy. \tag{1}
$$
If so, we can find it as follows: comparing $(1)$ with
$$
du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy, \tag{2}
$$
we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \left(\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right) &\Rightarrow
u(x,y) = x\log(x^2+y^2) + f(x) \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \log(x^2+y^2) + \frac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}
+ f'(x). \tag{3}
\end{align}
Comparing $({3})$ with the coefficient of $dx$ in $(1)$, we conclude that $f'(x)=0$,
so $f(x)=C$ and, finally,
$$
u(x,y) = x\log(x^2+y^2) + C, \tag{4}
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much :)